# How can I compact lots of small Try-Catch blocks when handling exceptions in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, try-catch

In my object conversion code I have tons of:

```
    try
    {
        NativeObject.Property1= int.Parse(TextObject.Property1);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Trace.WriteLineIf(ConverterSwitch.TraceVerbose, e);
    }
    try
    {
        NativeObject.Property2= DateTime.Parse(TextObject.Property2);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Trace.WriteLineIf(ConverterSwitch.TraceVerbose, e);
    }
```

And so on... I do not want all conversion to fail cause of some property so I can't put all this in one try block, but I need to log if something fails and continue..
**Is there a way to compact all this try catch things?**

Pity we can't write in C# code like:

```
try
{
    int num = int.Parse("3");
    decimal num2 = decimal.Parse("3.4");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Trace.Write(e);
    continue; //continue execution from the point we left. (line 2)
}
```

Comment: If you switch to VB.NET, you could use `On Error Resume Next` :-)

Comment: Somewhere a VB6/VBA developer is snickering at you. Never thought I'd hear someone pine for "On error resume next"

Comment: @Cody: Oh, God.  Oh, God no.  Please, no.

Comment: You should be using a tryParse and *validating* your data. If data has a chance to be invalid, it should be validated, Exceptions are horribly inefficient. Exceptions actually causes a cpu interrupt. Talking about thousands of cycles.

Comment: @Bengie: I agree that exceptions are slow, I will surely add some validation checks later, i don't want to waste time on optimization for now.

Comment: @Broken Pipe: tryParse would've been less work than try/catch if done at the beginning, then it wouldn't have been an "optimization". But what's done is done, and going back will take more time. :*(

Comment: Funny thing, I have just spent 5 mins wondering why my continue; statement doesn't compile in foreach loop, I completely forgot that I was using Try(()=>{;}) anonymous method instead of usual Try block :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No but you can:

```
private static void ExecuteAndCatchException(Action action)
{
  try 
  { 
    action();
  } 
  catch (Exception e) 
  { 
    Trace.Write(e); 
  } 
}
```

and then

```
ExecuteAndCatchException(() => NativeObject.Property1 = int.Parse(TextObject.Property1)); 
ExecuteAndCatchException(() => NativeObject.Property2 = DateTime.Parse(TextObject.Property2));
```

Comment: It's a shame this won't actually compile from typos... :P

Comment: @cdhowie, oops, I did not try to compile it, where are the typos?

Comment: @vc: `Action();` -- also, the method should really be static since `this` is never used.

Answer (score 13):

You could use the TryParse methods, when available. See below sample code for parsing an Int32 value.

```
   private static void TryToParse(string value)
   {
      int number;
      bool result = Int32.TryParse(value, out number);
      if (result)
      {
         Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1}.", value, number);         
      }
      else
      {
         if (value == null) value = ""; 
         Console.WriteLine("Attempted conversion of '{0}' failed.", value);
      }
   }
```

Comment: Yes, this is the correct approach, assuming that the sample code from the question accurately depicts the extent of what you want to accomplish with these nested Try-Catch blocks. It's always better to *prevent* exceptions when possible rather than trying to handle them.

Comment: Good answer! +1 for solving the actual problem instead of answering a question about the workaround.

Comment: +1 TryParse is the better way to go if you want to ignore parsing errors.

Comment: @BobBlack: well my real code is not so simple as I wrote, so the general aproach with Action<> is better for me.

Comment: Was just about to suggest this myself but you beat me to it :)

Comment: I think there are too many thumbs up for this answer since it doesn't really answer the question. I totally agree with the fact that when available TryParse methods are a much better choice than the try/catch counterparts, but the question was about compacting code and this reply doesn't provide a solution. Probably a combination between the replies that recommend encapsulating the conversion in a separate method and this one would have been the best answer.

Answer (score 4):

You could do something like this:

```
private static void Attempt(Action action)
{
    try { action(); }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Trace.WriteLineIf(ConverterSwitch.TraceVerbose, e);
    }
}
```

Then:

```
Attempt(() => NativeObject.Property1 = int.Parse(TextObject.Property1));
Attempt(() => NativeObject.Property2 = DateTime.Parse(TextObject.Property2));
```

Answer (score 1):

It sound like you're looking for something akin to VBs `On Error` + `Resume Next`.  C# has no such facility.  The best way of compacting I can think of is to use lambda expressions and helper methods.

```
private void Wrap(Action del) {
  try {
    del();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    Trace.WriteLineIf(ConverterSwitch.TraceVerbose, e);
  }
}

Wrap(() => { NativeObject.Property1= int.Parse(TextObject.Property1); });
Wrap(() => { NativeObject.Property2= DateTime.Parse(TextObject.Property2); });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a SafeConvert class that encapsulates the converting and logging as such:

```
public static class SafeConvert{

  public static int ParseInt(string val)
  {
    int retval = default;
    try 
    { 
       retval = int.Parse(val); 
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    { 
        Trace.WriteLineIf(ConverterSwitch.TraceVerbose, e); 
    } 
        return retval;
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I'm not sure about the Exception block shortening, I like the idea you've proposed. It's similar to On Error Resume Next in VB of old. When doing loads of Parse-ing, I'd go down the route of using TryParse when it's available. You could then say something like:

```
If(!DateTime.TryParse(TextObject.Property2, out NativeObject.Property2)) {
    // Failed!
}
```